ElasticSearch: Search through all indices, and get the results with the exact query
I'm trying to search through all indices on ElasticSearch, and only show the results which are an exact match for my query. I would specify a field, but some my indices have different field names for the same thing, so it would not work very well.
I've tried this query:
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "sigma@gmail.com",
      "fields": ["*"]
    }
  }
}

This does work for searching through all fields, but it gets everything which contains "sigma@gmail.com" rather than only getting the results which have that exact string in any of the fields. Is there any way to make the query so it only gets the results which are an exact match to the query, rather than it returning any results which contains the query?
This is a sample of the result from the above query:
{
  "took": 7941,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 13,
    "successful": 13,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 16.785738,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "[REDACTED]",
        "_id": "g1qD0o8BspIBF6pui4tY",
        "_score": 16.785738,
        "_source": {
          "email": "sigma@gmail.com",
          "password": "[REDACTED]"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "[REDACTED]",
        "_id": "EQ_G2o8Bscm15FIBl7mN",
        "_score": 12.5678215,
        "_source": {
          "email": "satish1.sigma@gmail.com",
          "display_name": "[REDACTED]",
          "username": "[REDACTED]",
          "followers": 1,
          "created_at": "Wed Dec 05 08:01:45 +0000 2012"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "[REDACTED]",
        "_id": "k7bG048BspIBF6puMOJK",
        "_score": 10.896135,
        "_source": {
          "id": 114820652,
          "username": "[REDACTED]",
          "email": "alice.64.sigma@gmail.com",
          "password": null,
          "ip": "[REDACTED]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


which version of elastic are you running?

@Menelaos I'm using version 8.4.1

as I asked in the comments of the answer... you want to limit the returned result to the matching field/key?

@Menelaos I want to only return the results which contain the exact query string in any field. For example, "sigma@gmail.com" should only return results matching exactly "sigma@gmail.com", rather than also returning results like "satish1.sigma@gmail.com"

Not sure if that's possible... but you could specify to only include email in the response. Add   "_source": {
"includes": ["resultData.email"]
}, as in my answer update. This will exclude sensitive fields, like password.

Doesn't seem like it's possible with ElasticSearch itself. The way I got around it is by checking if the query is an exact match, client-side using my React.js application.

Did you try specifying specific fields? e.g.   "_source": {
"includes": ["email"]
}. In some case, if you are searching for e-mail, it would make sense to show only e-mail.

@Menelaos Due to the nature of how the site functions, it has to show all of the data in the record. My solution isn't ideal, but it works at least.

Introduction
Give the following approaches a try:
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "sigma@gmail.com",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}

OR
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"sigma@gmail.com\"",
      "default_operatro": "AND"
      "fields": ["*"]      
    }
  }
}

Please inform if it works - I will personally test something similar in the coming minutes.
Update
If the purpose is to limit the returned fields for matching documents, the following might work well - which should return only email.
Trying to think of how to modify the includes dynamically depending on the result...
Not sure if it's possible dynamically, but you could specify specific fields and leave out sensitive fields like password.
E.g.
 "_source": {
        "includes": ["email"]
      },

AND
GET /_search
{
   "_source": {
    "includes": ["email"]
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "query": "sigma@gmail.com",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }}


I've just tested this query and it seems to do the same thing as mine. It returns everything which contains that query, rather than just ones which match exactly.

@almighty , you are saying you want to limit the result output?? Not get the full json of the matching JSON-document?

I've tested both queries, and they still seem to output the same result as mine does
